# After passing testID to Stack.Screen, testID is not recognized by detox

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, e2e-testing, react-navigation-stack, detox

After installing and configuring detox in react native app to run e2e test. It failed to recognize `testID` that was passed to the `options` object of `Stack.Screen`

Home component

```tsx
import { React } from 'React';
import { createStackNavigator, StackNavigationOptions } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Text testID="homeText">Detox</Text>
      </View>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Hello">
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Hello"
          options={
            {
              title: 'Hello World',
              testID: 'helloScreen',
            } as StackNavigationOptions
          }>
          {() => <Text>Hello World</Text>}
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="WelcomeBack"
          options={
            {
              title: 'Welcome back',
              testID: 'welcomeBackScreen',
            } as StackNavigationOptions
          }>
          {() => <Text>Welcome back</Text>}
        </Stack.Screen>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And e2e test

```ts
describe('Home Screen', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should display "Detox" text', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('homeText'))).toHaveText('Detox');
  }); // [OK]

  it('should display "Hello World" text', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('helloScreen'))).toBeVisible();
  }); // [FAIL]

  it('should display "Welcome back" text', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('welcomeBackScreen'))).toBeVisible();
  }); // [FAIL]
});
```

When the test is executed it fails on

**Detox Runtime**

```detox
Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(id == “helloScreen”)”
.
.
.
Test Failed: No elements found for “MATCHER(id == “welcomeBackScreen”)”
```

Comment: I see you are passing testID but not using it in any of the component.

Comment: @DevAKS Yes. I want to check if the stack.screen itself is available before reaching the Text

Comment: Detox is primarily designed for testing mobile apps with interaction on the UI elements of the app. Detox operates at the level of the app's UI layer, and it may not be able to directly access the implementation details of the app's navigation stack.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was able to work through it.